# Is "signup for registration" redundant?

Tags: programming, redundancy

I'm writing a document for an exercise-project spec. The line goes:

> A simple registration website where visitors can view registered users and *signup for registration* themselves.

Is this being redundant? I feel the need to use the word register as this will make it apparent that signing up makes a visitor registered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The act of signing up may be only one aspect of the registration process, so in that case it would not be redundant to refer to both. It would be simpler just to use the verb *register*, however.